# Formatted address in Foursquare Venues Search includes only country name

Tags: foursquare

**venueID**: 51b06376498ea421e382bce2

That venue is pointing to a place name, in English: "G Village, Thailand"

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/51b06376498ea421e382bce2?locale=th&v=20161208

---

The following are responses received with 2 different locales: `en` and `th`.

> formatted-address (th): "ประเทศไทย"
>
> formatted-address (en): "Thailand"

Comment: Hey Roylee. What's the question here? Have you read about internationalization in Foursquare docs? https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning

Comment: Yes, I have read the doc. I'm sorry if its not obvious. venueID is returning country name, i.e: thailand in formatted_address field, where I'm expecting "G Village" to be in formatted_address. I'm wondering if this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the Foursquare.com page for that [venue](https://foursquare.com/v/g-village/51b06376498ea421e382bce2) it shows the name is "G Village" and the only address data available is "Thailand".

I believe this would be expected behavior to only have "Thailand" returned in the `formatted-address`. If you are looking to get the "G Village" field from the API look under the `name` response field.

From the docs the `location` object will only contain:

> An object containing none, some, or all of address (street address), 
>   crossStreet,  city, state, postalCode,  country, lat, lng, and
>   distance. All fields are strings, except for lat, lng, and distance.
>   Distance is measured in meters.

If you know the complete address you should suggest an edit back to Foursquare.